# Button Active Only When All Checkboxes Checked

Tags: jquery

How to create something like this:

If user clicked two checkboxes then button (name="save") is active, else this button is not active

```
<label>
<input id="accepted1" type="checkbox" />Please accept
</label>
<label>
<input id="accepted2" type="checkbox" /> Please accept2
</label>


<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#warning" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="id_complete" name="save">Complete Order</button>
```

I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Codesleuth/swqmX/1/

```
$('#accepted1,#accepted2').click(function () {
  if ($('#accepted1:checked,#accepted2:checked').length == 2)
    $('#id_complete').removeAttr('disabled');
  else
    $('#id_complete').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

And remember to have your buttons disabled by default:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="id_complete" name="save" disabled="disabled">Complete Order</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want to set the button to not show (using CSS) at first. Then, as each of the inputs is changed, check to see if both inputs are currently checked, if they are, then set the button to be displayed.

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    if($('#accepted1').is(':checked') && $('#accepted2').is(':checked'))
        // show the button
    } else {
        // hide the button
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vw6N4/1/

Comment: There is an else block missing to hide it again, if the user unchecks one the checkboxes again.

Answer (score 1):

Set the button to be disabled by default (by adding a `disabled="disabled"` HTML attribute to the button). Then use the `is(":checked")` check that jQuery offers, like:

```
$("input[id^=\"accepted\"]").change(function() {
    if($("#accepted1").is(":checked") && $("#accepted2").is(":checked")) {
        $("#id_complete").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#id_complete").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Also see this live [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v57ha/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure that the button is initially disabled

```
$("#id_complete").attr("disabled", "disabled");   



 $('input).on('change', function() {
      var c1 = $('#accepted1').is(":checked");
      var c2 = $('#accepted2').is(":checked");

    if(c1 && c2){
       $("#id_complete").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else{
       $("#id_complete").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
if ( $('checkbox:checked').length == $('checkbox').length )
  $('button[name="save"]').removeAttr('disabled');
else
  $('button[name="save"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Better to add specific class to all required checkboxes and check not `$('checkbox:checked').length == $('checkbox').length`, but `$('checkbox.required:checked').length == $('checkbox.required').length`

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkSave() {
   if ($("input[id^=accepted]:checked").length == $("input[id^=accepted]").length) {
      $("#id_complete").prop('disabled', false);
   }
   else {
      $("#id_complete").prop('disabled', true);
   }
}
checkSave();
$("input[id^=accepted]").change(checkSave);
```

This handles on page load as well.

Comment: Is this solution working? [http://jsfiddle.net/rY6ms/](http://jsfiddle.net/rY6ms/)

Comment: @user1479606 just had a small syntax error in one of the selectors; it's fixed now http://jsfiddle.net/rY6ms/1/

Comment: I still cannot see any difference [http://jsfiddle.net/rY6ms/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/rY6ms/2/)

Comment: @user1479606 use my link, not yours

Answer (score 0):

I would add the class check to each of the checkboxes, then you can simply check if both are checked like this.  Also, I would add a disabled attribute to the complete button in your HTML.

```
$(".check").click(function () {
  if ($(".check:checked").length == 2) 
    $("#id_complete").removeAttr("disabled");
  else 
    $("#id_complete").attr("disabled", "");
});
```

Sample fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/c578C/1/

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers seem a little long-winded, there's a much simpler way to achieve this.

First, give all the elements which you require to be checked a class of `check-required`, then simply compare the `length` or `check-required` against the length of `check-required:checked` to set the `disabled` property on the `button`, eg:

```
$('.check-required').change(function() {
  $('#id_complete').prop('disabled', $('.check-required').length !== $('.check-required:checked').length);
}).change();
```

You should also trigger the `change` event on page load as shown above.

The major benefit of this over the other answers is that if you needed to add more checkboxes, as long as you give them the `check-required` class the code will continue to work as desired.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvdHX/)